# Nginx redirect with vue not working

Tags: nginx, redirect

EDIT:
I'm serving my node backend with proxy_pass like:

```
 location / {
   allow all;
 }

 location /backend {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:60702;
      # Some headers
 }
```

When removing this file it works as I want. Why is this part causing all the errors?

---

Well, now I got just another problem with some redirects in Vue/nginx.

Now I am hosting vue with nginx and set the root directory to `/var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist`.
When typing in some path to the URL like "https://url.de/pathname" I get errors equivalent to:

`*2 open() "/var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist/app" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

Why is it checking for a directory in dist like that? It should stay on the same page or redirect to the paths specified in vue like `router.push('/home')`

Nginx conf location block is:

```
location / {
   # point to dist folder inside vue source code folder
   root /var/www/client/pvapp-client/dist;
   autoindex on;
   autoindex_exact_size off;
   index index.html index.htm;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, for future people looking for this here's the solution.

To the Nginx node config (your backend) add:

```
error_page 404 =200 /index.html;
```

Before the location block. That redirects all paths that are not found to the **current** page.